# Is this any issues with passing into multiple domain objects into a ViewModelBuilders in asp.net-mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I have been trying to refactoring my app to support [all the things mentioned in this blog post](http://paulstovell.com/blog/clean-aspnet-mvc-controllers) to thin out my controllers.  The one issue i wanted to clarify is in the article, the ViewModelBuilder always seems to take one domain object and convert it to one viewmodel

In my case, I have many cases where my ViewModelBuilder class takes in several domainobjects to convert to a single ViewModel object (sometimes 5 or 6)

This is because many of my views are showing information with multiple domain objects.

I just wanted to make sure in terms of the view model builder pattern if there was anything wrong with the approach of doing something like this in my controller

```
  public ActionResult GetView()
  {
         var appDomainObjects = _service1.GetApps();
         var carDomainObjects = _service2.GetCars();
         var dogDomainObjects = _service1.GetDogs();
         var viewModel = new MyViewModelBuilder().BuildViewModel(appDomainObjects, carDomainObjects, dogDomainObjects);
         return View(viewModel);
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's absolutely nothing wrong with your approach. Quite at the contrary this is the correct pattern of how a typical GET controller action looks like. It maps one or more domain models to a view model which gets passed to the view.